# Post dictionary with image on server

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

Kindly check the code To save a dictionary with following details:

```
City = DGJHK;
    Country = DGHJEK;
    DOB = "11/28/2016";
    FirstName = GWK;
    LastName = FDJKJ;
    MiddleName = FDJWHK;
    State = DGJEHK;
    UpdatedImage = <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01000048 00480000 ffe10058 45786966 00004d4d 002a0000 00080002 01120003 00000001 00010000 87690004 00000001 00000026 00000000 0003a001 00030000 00010001 0000a002 00040000 00010000 0280a003 00040000 00010000 01aa0000 0000ffed 00385068 6f746f73 686f7020 332e3000 3842494d 04040000 00000000 3842494d 04250000 00000010 d41d8cd9 8f00b204 e9800998 ecf8427e ffc00011 0801aa02 80030111 00021101 031101ff c4001f00 00010501 01010101 01000000 00000000 00010203 04050607 08090a0b ffc400b5 10000201 03030204 03050504 04000001 7d010203 00041105 12213141 06135161 07227114 328191a1 082342b1 c11552d1 f0243362 7282090a 16171819 1a252627 28292a34 35363738 393a4344 45464748 494a5354 55565758 595a6364 65666768 696a7374 75767778 797a8384 85868788 898a9293 94959697 98999aa2 a3a4a5a6 a7a8a9aa b2b3b4b5 b6b7b8b9 bac2c3c4 c5c6c7c8 c9cad2d3 d4d5d6d7 d8d9dae1 e2e3e4e5 e6e7e8e9 eaf1f2f3 f4f5f6f7 f8f9faff c4001f01 00030101 01010101 01010100 00000000 00010203 04050607 08090a0b ffc400b5 11000201 02040403 04070504 04000102 77000102 03110405 21310612 41510761 71132232 81081442 91a1b1c1 09233352 f0156272 d10a1624 34e125f1 1718191a 26272829 2a353637 38393a43 44454647 48494a53 54555657 58595a63 64656667 68696a73 74757677 78797a82 83848586 8788898a 92939495 96979899 9aa2a3a4 a5a6a7a8 a9aab2b3 b4b5b6b7 b8b9bac2 c3c4c5c6 c7c8c9ca d2d3d4d5 d6d7d8d9 dae2e3e4 e5e6e7e8 e9eaf2f3 f4f5f6f7 f8f9faff db004300 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 ffdb0043 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01ffdd00 040050ff da000c03 01000211 0311003f 00fe393c 51e31b0d 23c6be1c d7f45b4f f48f1478 77c3fabd 85cdfd8a dd41a5f8 93473a9e 9ba75ec5 776d2bbc 97823fec a8ae358b 6304d6f3 492c97f6 534667b4 97f38cb7 2d956cab 1182ab5a 51581c4e 2b0f5950 adcb3ab8 6ace9549 537095ad 4a57aad5 1946d27a d29abc27 1fbeccf1 f1a39ad2 c5d2c3c1 c719470d 8aa32ab4 94a0ab41 4e0a6b96 525cca5a 4aa42575 b35aa52f 54f11fc4 1f1669fe 06f0cf8f 6cf5efb3 dcf813c5 ac93dc2c 36335cdf dc6a1a76 9ba76b1a 4cf7d059 08e3b386 1d3a0b58 ed85cdc5 bcb61f69 b5def716 f24107ce e132cc3c 336af93a c34e54f1 785f6f84 97b5aabe aee94e72 a53b39cb 99d4954e 794254e0 ef2bd9d3 9ae6fa3a 99b62618 2c36754b 13ec7118 5afc9564 a9d35ed1 4ed1a8a4 dd35a535 1e5e74e6 9abc5b53 3b5f137c 7e83c3fa cf8463f0 e5e787ac fc396306 a96fe2fd 0f4a55f3 2ca5f186 9f6baec7 7d750ea4 b369faad d58092e6 ca0d4ade da58d6c6 5b6b2329 5450df3d 82e0f9e2 f29cde96 330f89a9 88751bc9 b1189577 3860aacf 0ea9d2a9 45aa9875 271a73a7 0e68548d 4f693579 a728ed8e cd683c66 1a92c4c1 616ad3f6 598a84bd 9d4c155c 4d35529d 783924da 8ddc9d48 c5c24ba4 5b48f52d 77c32de3 bf094de2 af06e950 ebda37c3 fd0a3d23 55f05dc5 a1b8f12d adb6af65 1c02c7ed 766268ae b497d27c e4d3b57b 4325e2c7 2595a1b6 92490d7c 7e598f96 498da195 e6f8b860 f1f9ce23 dbd1cd69 fee7015a b519ce50 c4a85694 26b11eda 3075b0f5 1d2a71a9 ed5a9724 5737a32c 354a1819 51a14bdb fb0a3561 5aaca9c2 af3ca70e 4a9774da 9c1ce0a3 52329c7d fb2e58ce c409e10d 42f340d2 bc57f083 c3cbe26d 2b4bd02c e07fb7dd dbd9f897 4db64b1b ebf7d52c cc97cb7b f69b7d02 da5b4d4a c19574f7 d4225b81 a75d2ea5 6d7b69e9 60f388d0 c762f079 f63560f1 953132b4 69d294f0 1886e4a9 b525cbec a2ab62bf dde70a95 6ac68b95 3f68a54b 925e7d58 62561a8c a51a78ca 7254a385 af194a18 9a295182 aadcd41a 8ab4a165 55cb9a69 ded65cbf 01789fcc d2fe2269 977a5cda 9596bbfd 9ad6f77a c48c2f6d fc4d8d2a 181e1965 4f3c7dbf 5394cd69 7b7b78e7 75e5ec2f 7c818c8d 5fb8e0dc 6b6555e3 5fd955a1 ed172d18 374e5857 ed1caff6 13a705cb 38420afe ce2dabcb e1f85c44 65473384 a829c6b4 60e12ad6 e6862546 1cba3b27 7a8ed19c e6d5a6e2 9a4ddce8 fc4adaaf 8f3c51a0 6bde13d4 9fc2f7d1 d97882e6 7d235299 6eb4fd3b c476337d 9fc4b63f 6b86d6da fe31a9c7 f66bbd6a 1bfb6d8a f7177242 d2dbc224 6e4a1f55 }
```

I am using the following code to POST it on server:

```
    -(void)sendUserUpdatedDetailsToServer:(NSDictionary *)details withToken:(NSString*)token{


        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: sessionConfig delegate: self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];


        NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:details options:0 error:nil];

        NSLog(@"%@",[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil]);

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/updateuserprofile",serviceUrl, token]]];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];


        currentSerType = SendUserUpdateDetails;

        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request];
        [dataTask resume];

    }



    - (IBAction)saveAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {


        NSLog(@"the values stored in dictionary are %@",_userDetailsDictionary);

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_userDetailsDictionary forKey:@"UpdatedDetails"];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        ConnectionManager * connectionManager = [ConnectionManager sharedConnectionManager];
        connectionManager.delegate = self;
        [connectionManager sendUserUpdatedDetailsToServer:_userDetailsDictionary withToken:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"token"]];



    }
```

This code works well if i don't save image but when i choose image to save,it gives crash.Please tell what is wrong in this code. What should i do to save the image also in dictionary and post it on server?

Comment: convert the image into base64 format

Comment: check if server need header `'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'`

Answer (score 0):

you can choose to convert **UIImage** to **NSData**

then convert **NSData** to **NSString**  using **Base64Encoding**

finally add to your dictionary to post it to server

**UIImage** to **Base64Encoding NSString**

```
    UIImage *originImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your-image-name.png"];

    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(originImage, 1.0f);

    NSString *base64ImageString = [data base64Encoding];
```

**Base64Encoding NSString** to **UIImage**

```
    NSData *decodedImageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64Encoding:base64ImageString];

    UIImage *decodedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:decodedImageData];
```